# simple AWS AppSync schema and resolver for ElasticSearch service

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, graphql, aws-appsync

I'd like to get simple AppSync resolver for EslasticSearch service this way:

Schema:

```
type Query {
  searchESIndex(input: ESModelTypeInput!): ESModelRespType
}

input ESModelTypeInput {
  es_body: String
  es_index_name: String
}

type ESModelRespType {
  es_resp: String
}
```

So the point is to give only index name where to search and the body string that contains full stingified body or query
and to return back full response of ElasticSearch as a string (for further parsing)

Resolver:

```
{
  "version":"2017-02-28",
  "operation":"GET",
  "path":"/$context.args.es_index_name/_search",
  "params":{
      "body": $util.toJson("$context.args.es_body")
      }
  }
}
```

Response template:

```
## i need full result as a string, but how to convert it?
$context.result
```

The Query would be:

```
query searchESIndex($esinput: ESModelTypeInput!) {
  searchESIndex(input: $esinput) {
    es_resp
  }
}
```

Variables:

```
{
    "esinput": {
        "es_index_name": "test2",
        "es_body": "{\"size\": 10}"
  }
}
```

Also i supposed to have similar mutation

```
type Mutation {
    insertToESIndex(input: ESModelTypeInput!): ESModelRespType
}
```

Unfortunately, all my tries were failed.
Is it possible to do it?
Could you help me with that?

Comment: Your response will be JSON and one way to convert it to string is by using $util.dynamodb.toString(...). Have you tried this? Also, is there any specific reason you are defining 'ESModelRespType' whereas as you could just do 'type Query {searchESIndex(input: ESModelTypeInput!): String}'? Can you also share the error you are getting?

Comment: Also, I think there is a mistake in how you are testing your query. According to your definition of query, 'es_resp' is nested in 'ESModelRespType', so in order you to test it, the correct query syntax should be 'query searchESIndex($esinput:ESModelTypeInput!) {searchESIndex(input: $esinput) {ESModelRespType:{es_resp}}}'.

Comment: $util.dynamodb.toString(...) causes this:
"message": "Invocation of method 'toString' in  class com.amazonaws.deepdish.transform.util.DynamoDBUtils threw exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments at velocity[line 15, column 16]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel obligated to update my answer as @cyberwombat pointed out a better solution than I posted previously.

You can convert your result into stringified JSON by following ways.

**Option 1:**

```
#set($resultMap = {})

#foreach($key in $ctx.result.keySet())
    $util.qr($resultMap.put("$key", $ctx.result.get($key)))
#end

#return($util.escapeJavaScript($util.toJson($resultMap)))
```

**Option 2:**

You can convert your resolver to Pipeline and created a simple Lambda function in NodeJS to stringify the JSON object. This is how you lambda function should look like:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(event.input.serviceConfig).replace(/\"/g, '\\\"'),
    };
    callback(null, response)
};
```

You can now easily use the returned string in your resolver and get the stringified JSON.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62518428/stringify-json-object-for-sql-query-in-aws-appsync/62707014#62707014) to my question, explanation and complete answer.