# Migrate from AWS AppSync to Apollo GraphQL (Javascript)

Tags: aws-appsync

I am fairly new to GraphQL and have been using AWS AppSync service for GraphQL APIs. I use AWS Cognito for authentication/authorization, some Lambda functions and also have serverless RDS instance that is connected to my API. My question is:

How can I or is there a way to migrate from AppSync to Apollo GraphQL implementation in Javascript with least amount of rewriting the code and keeping the data sources as they are?

Reasons:

1. No support for versioning in AppSync. I am unable to find way to revert back to an old version of my API. Currently, I backup my API by downloading the schema.json from AppSync and backup all my resolvers in a text file.
2. If code gets bigger, browser gets unresponsive and takes good amount of time to load for the first time.
3. Helper functions in $util serves great but at some points, I find it lacking somethings that I want to do differently. To work around this, I use Lambda functions. Therefore, no support for adding custom modules or libraries in AppSync.
4. Sometimes, testing and debugging a resolver can be really frustrating. I am used to print on console and I find it really helpful.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are able to create Lambda Functions with modules, see [AWS Lambda deployment package in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html), in the Lambda Developer Guide.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. What I meant by it was that there is no support for adding more helper functions, or modules or libraries in AppSync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an answer on migration but more of some thoughts on your issues that you might consider.

1. Versioning. You might explore working offline using either [serverless](https://www.serverless.com/) or AWS's own [SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) - that way you'd be able to version your configs.
2. Browser gets unresponsive - My guess this is not going to get resolved by migration - perhaps there is a design issue that could be improved here.
3. Helper functions in $util - I understand though you can often find workarounds. VTL is pretty powerful (though annoying sometimes) and I've never had to rely on a Lamdba except to do things far beyond the scope of any helper (running JSON Schema validators for ex). But I can see how it would be nice to write your own for sure.
4. Debugging - Going offline with one of the solutions in #1 is going to help there. I don't have much experience with SAM but I use serverless very extensively and the appsync offline options offer debugging.

Perhaps this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions. Yes, I am wanting to work offline and I will look into these framworks. Regarding your comment about the browser issue, I break down my API into smaller part but it does not work all the time. By that I mean some APIs cannot be broken down and are already optimized. Regarding $util, I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62518428/stringify-json-object-for-sql-query-in-aws-appsync/62707014#62707014) question a while ago. Although it's such an easy task but I was not able to find any solution but to create a Lambda function.

Comment: @Myz I posted an answer to your  `$util` issue. Admittedly that one is a pain because of all the quotes and escaping. As far as your api though.... how is migrating to a different backend going to change the structure of your api? Or rather - what kind of structure will you be able to do on standalone Apollo that you cannot do on AppSync?